# How to selenium on python

Tags: selenium

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='btn_aplist_export'][@type='button']"}
```

> ```
> <div id="btn_area">
> <input type="button" name="btn_aplist_export" id="btn_aplist_export" bt="btn71" value="AP List Export"
> ```
>
> onclick="run_aplist_export();" class="input_normal hiding"
> style="float:left;margin-right:10px;" adflag="1" swflag="1"
> autocomplete="off">

Comment: What is the website? Cannot debug with just one line. Please post the code that you have written. Also, post webstie url if possible. Thanks!